# Is there a natural homotopy inverse to the map $∣Sing(X)∣\rightarrow X$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff

Let $Sing:C \rightarrow SSet$ be the functor sending a CW complex to its singular complex (a simplicial set).

Let $∣-∣: SSet \rightarrow C$ be the geometric realization functor.

For every $X$ we have a natural map that is a homotopy equivalence $\epsilon_X: ∣Sing(X)∣\rightarrow X$.

Is there a natural homotopy inverse? Said differently, is there a natural transformation $\text {Id} \Rightarrow∣Sing(-)∣$ consisting of homotopy inverses to the $\epsilon_X$’s?

Comment: No, use naturality for the inclusions of points into a space $X$.

Comment: Could you write with more detail?

Comment: Yes, I too would appreciate more details!